# Use google bigquery to build histogram graph

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can write a query that makes histogram graph rendering easier?

For example, we have 100 million people with ages, we want to draw the histogram/buckets for age 0-10, 11-20, 21-30 etc... What does the query look like?

Has anyone done it? Did you try to connect the query result to google spreadsheet to draw the histogram?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the [2019 update, with #standardSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56447260/132438) --Fh

---

The subquery idea works, as does "CASE WHEN" and then doing a group by:

```
SELECT COUNT(field1), bucket 
FROM (
    SELECT field1, CASE WHEN age >=  0 AND age < 10 THEN 1
                        WHEN age >= 10 AND age < 20 THEN 2
                        WHEN age >= 20 AND age < 30 THEN 3
                        ...
                        ELSE -1 END as bucket
    FROM table1) 
GROUP BY bucket
```

Alternately, if the buckets are regular -- you could just divide and cast to an integer:

```
SELECT COUNT(field1), bucket 
FROM (
    SELECT field1, INTEGER(age / 10) as bucket FROM table1)
GROUP BY bucket
```

Comment: You could make things more clear by naming the buckets with strings like `"0 <= age < 10"`, `"10 <= age < 20"`, etc.  Also, doesn't `SUM(field1)` sum the values of the ages?  I think you want to do `SELECT 1` to only count each age within the bucket once.

Comment: Should these queries use COUNT(field1) rather than SUM(field1)?

Comment: @MattFaus, `0 <= age < 10` is `0 <= age OR age < 10`, at least in BigQuery land.

Comment: My naming suggestion was meant to be human readable, not machine.

Comment: Yes @Valis -- that should be **COUNT(field1)**.

Comment: @Jordan Tigani  I've edited this to use COUNT as the aggregation function, because standard hisograms count the number of items in each bin.

Answer (score 21):

You could also use the [`quantiles`](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions) aggregation operator to get a quick look at the distribution of ages.

```
SELECT
  quantiles(age, 10)
FROM mytable
```

Each row of this query would correspond to the age at that point in the list of ages.  The first result is the age 1/10ths of the way through the sorted list of ages, the second is the age 2/10ths through, 3/10ths, etc.

Comment: This is a legacy SQL parameter, which need to be specified when running it. Standard SQL now has an APPROXIMATE_QUANTILES function.

Comment: In BigQuery the function is `APPROX_QUANTILES`. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#approx_quantiles

Comment: `APPROX_QUANTILES` splits data into buckets, but does not provide "counts" of how many elements are in each bucket:

Answer (score 11):

With #standardSQL and an auxiliary `stats` query, we can define the range the histogram should look into.

Here for the time to fly between SFO and JFK - with 10 buckets:

```
WITH data AS ( 
    SELECT *, ActualElapsedTime datapoint
    FROM `fh-bigquery.flights.ontime_201903`
    WHERE FlightDate_year = "2018-01-01" 
    AND Origin = 'SFO' AND Dest = 'JFK'
)
, stats AS (
  SELECT min+step*i min, min+step*(i+1)max
  FROM (
    SELECT max-min diff, min, max, (max-min)/10 step, GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 10, 1) i
    FROM (
      SELECT MIN(datapoint) min, MAX(datapoint) max
      FROM data
    )
  ), UNNEST(i) i
)

SELECT COUNT(*) count, (min+max)/2 avg
FROM data 
JOIN stats
ON data.datapoint >= stats.min AND data.datapoint<stats.max
GROUP BY avg
ORDER BY avg
```

If you need round numbers, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159876/132438

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using a cross join to get your min and max values (not that expensive on a single tuple) you can get a normalized bucket list of any given bucket count:

```
select
  min(data.VAL) as min,
  max(data.VAL) as max,
  count(data.VAL) as num,
  integer((data.VAL-value.min)/(value.max-value.min)*8) as group
from [table] data
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(VAL) as max, MIN(VAL) as min, from [table]) value
GROUP BY group
ORDER BY group
```

in this example we're getting 8 buckets (pretty self explanatory) plus one for null VAL

Answer (score 1):

Write a subquery like this:

```
(SELECT '1' AS agegroup, count(*) FROM people WHERE AGE <= 10 AND AGE >= 0)
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT '1' AS agegroup, count(*) FROM people WHERE AGE <= 10 AND AGE >= 0),
(SELECT '2' AS agegroup, count(*) FROM people WHERE AGE <= 20 AND AGE >= 10),
(SELECT '3' AS agegroup, count(*) FROM people WHERE AGE <= 120 AND AGE >= 20)
```

Result will be like:

```
Row agegroup count 
1   1       somenumber
2   2       somenumber
3   3       another number
```

I hope this helps you. Of course in the age group you can write anything like: '0 to 10'

Answer (score 1):

There is now the [APPROX_QUANTILES](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions#approx_quantiles) aggregation function in standard SQL.

```sql
SELECT
    APPROX_QUANTILES(column, number_of_bins)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [gamars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4610283/gamars) approach quite intriguing and expanded a little bit on it using scripting instead of the cross join. Notably, this approach also allows to consistently change group sizes, like here with group sizes that *increase exponentially*.

```sql
declare stats default 
    (select as struct min(new_confirmed) as min, max(new_confirmed) as max 
     from `bigquery-public-data.covid19_open_data.covid19_open_data` 
     where new_confirmed >0 and date = date "2022-03-07"
    );
declare group_amount default 10; -- change group amount here

SELECT 
    CAST(floor(
        (ln(new_confirmed-stats.min+1)/ln(stats.max-stats.min+1)) * (group_amount-1)) 
      AS INT64) group_flag,
    concat('[',min(new_confirmed),',',max(new_confirmed),']') as group_value_range,
    count(1) as quantity
FROM `bigquery-public-data.covid19_open_data.covid19_open_data`
where new_confirmed >0 and date = date "2022-03-07"
GROUP BY group_flag
ORDER BY group_flag ASC
```

The basic approach is to label each value with its `group_flag` and then group by it. The flag is calculated by scaling the value down to a value between 0 and 1 and then scale it up again to `0 - group_amount`.

I just took the log of the corrected value and range before their division to get the desired bias in group sizes. I also add 1 to make sure it doesn't try to take the log of 0.

[image: exponential data buckets]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a single vector of information. I would normally query it like this:

```
select
  count(*) as num,
  integer( age / 10 ) as age_group
from mytable
group by age_group
```

A big `case` statement will be needed for arbitrary groups. It would be simple but much longer. My example should be fine if every bucket contains N years.

Comment: integer is not a recognized function in BigQuery. Is there an alternative ot this by using cast?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the custom SQL functions. It works as

```
to_bin(10, [0, 100, 500]) => '... - 100'
to_bin(1000, [0, 100, 500, 0]) => '500 - ...'
to_bin(1000, [0, 100, 500]) => NULL
```

Read more here
https://github.com/AdamovichAleksey/BigQueryTips/blob/main/sql/functions/to_bins.sql

Any ideas and commits are welcomed