# BigQuery: Count elements in APPROX_QUNATILES

Tags: google-bigquery

I was wondering if there's a way to count how many elements are found in the buckets created by `APPROX_QUANTILES`? I guess what I'm actually looking for is a way to create histograms in BigQuery Standard SQL. Is there an option to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title of the question says "Count elements in APPROX_QUANTILES", and I'm going to answer that. As your ultimate goal is [to build a histogram, please see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56447260/132438).

To count the number of elements in each bucket, we can do something like:

```
WITH data AS ( 
    SELECT *, ActualElapsedTime datapoint
    FROM `fh-bigquery.flights.ontime_201903`
    WHERE FlightDate_year = "2018-01-01" 
    AND Origin = 'SFO' AND Dest = 'JFK'
  )
  , quantiles AS (
  SELECT *, IFNULL(LEAD(bucket_start) OVER(ORDER BY bucket_i) , 0100000) bucket_end
  FROM UNNEST((
    SELECT APPROX_QUANTILES(datapoint, 10)
    FROM data
  )) bucket_start WITH OFFSET bucket_i
) 

SELECT COUNT(*) count, bucket_i
  , ANY_VALUE(STRUCT(bucket_start, bucket_end)) b, MIN(datapoint) min,  MAX(datapoint) max
FROM data
JOIN quantiles
ON data.datapoint >= bucket_start AND data.datapoint < bucket_end
GROUP BY bucket_i
ORDER BY bucket_i
```

[image]

Visualized, we get something like:

[image]

Which tells us:

- Don't use `APPROX_QUANTILES` to build a histogram, because each bucket will end up having about the same amount of elements. That's the goal of a quantile.
- `APPROX_QUANTILES` is very "APPROX". As you can see each quantile didn't end up with the same amount of elements.
- It takes between ~305 and ~357 minutes to fly from SFO to JFK.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want the [`APPROX_TOP_COUNT` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#approx_top_count) instead, which returns frequency of the top elements up to a limit that you provide.

From the documentation:

```sql
SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(x, 2) as approx_top_count
FROM UNNEST(["apple", "apple", "pear", "pear", "pear", "banana"]) as x;

+-------------------------+
| approx_top_count        |
+-------------------------+
| [{pear, 3}, {apple, 2}] |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: No, as I have a continuous range of numbers, not categorical options.